# ionic2:show html tags with [innerHTML] and bind click event

Tags: onclick, ionic2, innerhtml

in html,code like below:

```
<div class="detail-style">
    <div [innerHTML]="html" *ngIf="html"></div>
  </div>
```

the `html` is some html tags like this:

```
<div><span>test</span></div>
<attach onclick="downloadAttach('attachName', 'attachPath')">click this to download attach</attach>
```

it can display properly,and when i click the attach,it throws `downloadAttach is not defined` exception, but i defined the `downloadAttach` method in ts file.
i don't know how to solve this problem.it took me a day.
thank you very very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

create

```
<script>function downloadAttach(){...}</script>
```

in your index.html